# create UUID from MostSignificantBits and LeastSignificantBits

Tags: java, uuid

As we know that we can get MostSignificantBits of UUID using method `getMostSignificantBits()` and LeastSignificantBits of UUID using method `getLeastSignificantBits()`. But , How to get the Original UUID(reverse process) if MostSignificantBits and LeastSignificantBits are known ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the UUID Constructor

UUID(long mostSigBits, long leastSigBits)

which constructs a new UUID using the specified data.